# why the string pointer is changing its value after calling a fuction that does not affect it?

Tags: c, string, pointers

this program is to extract the first and last names and whenever a extract the first names correctlly ( or the last names ) the other is changing its value to first ellement of the other's file

so if f1 contains Martin and f2 contains Joseph

when calling

```
GetPrenom(f2)
```

the result is

`Joseph`

but after calling

```
Getnom(f1)
```

the result changes to

`Martin`

this is my code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>      

char* GetNom(FILE* f1) {
    
    char* nam = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    fseek (f1, 0, SEEK_END);
    int length = ftell (f1);
    fseek (f1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char line1[length];
    fgets(line1, length, f1);
    nam = strtok(line1, " , ");
    rewind(f1);
    return nam ;
}
char* GetPrenom( FILE* f2) {
    
    char* lastname = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    fseek (f2, 0, SEEK_END);
    int length = ftell (f2);
    fseek (f2, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char line2[length];
    fgets(line2, length, f2);
    lastname  = strtok(line2, " ; ");
    rewind(f2);
    return lastname ;
}

int main() {
        FILE* f1 = ....; //openning the two files 
        FILE* f2 = ....;    

        char* prenom = GetPrenom(f2);
        char* nom = GetNom(f1);
        printf("%s \n", prenom);
        
    return 0;
}
```

what i expecte as a result is to have Joseph as first name but the result is the first str in f1 file which is Martin

so the pointer is changing its value without even passing by a function

Answer (score 0):

You carefully `malloc`-ed buffers, then ignored them and use stack-allocated arrays, and returned (*immediately* invalid) pointers to those stack arrays.

```
nam = strtok(line1, " , ");
```

does not, in any way, use the `malloc`ed memory `nam` originally pointed to, instead it throws away that pointer (leaking memory) and replaces it with a pointer to the first token within `line1` (a pointer that's actually guaranteed to be equivalent to the address of `line1`, `strtok` just went and mutated the string to cut it off where the first delimiter began).

The second call reused the same part of the stack for its stack-allocated array, stomping all over that memory.

The code was undefined behavior, so count yourself lucky all it did was replace one valid string with another.

What you wanted would be something like:

```
char* GetNom(FILE* f1) {
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);
    int length = ftell(f1);
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char line1[length + 1];
    fgets(line1, length + 1, f1);
    char *tok = strtok(line1, " , ");  // Tokenize to get first token
    char *nam = malloc(strlen(tok) + 1);  // Allocate exact space for first token, plus one for NUL
    strcpy(nam, tok);  // Copy data from token to malloc-ed buffer
    rewind(f1);
    return nam; // Return malloc-ed buffer, not pointer into transient line1
}
```

A similar change would be used for your other function.

Comment: @Fe2O3: True. Fixed.